How can I make a continuous texture on a non-flat surface?
I would like the text to run on the interface in such a way that it is easy to read


Hello, as Huy Pham says you need to unwrap again but there are several ways to project your image onto the surface so maybe tell a bit more

Looks like you need to UV unwrap your mesh.
Unless you want to project the texture onto it, which is a more difficult task.
